# Is there a way in intellij to specify a script in a MODULE that gets executed on "compile", "build" and/or "rebuild"

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way in intellij to specify a script in a MODULE that gets executed on "compile", "build" and/or "rebuild".  This to use for such things as code/resource generation etc.  This so if the module is included in another "PROJECT" it will "just work" in the new context.

If I could add an "artifact" to a MODULE ( not the project ) and specify building it "before compile" or "after compile" that would do the trick but it seems one can only create artifacts at the PROJECT level.

Answer (score 0):

In Run/Debug configuration there is "Before Launch field", its possible to put Ant/Maven script there: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html
Also it's possible to run custom script, if you set it as external third party tool: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-third-party-tools.html

Also there is Ant/Maven support.

Comment: Tje before launch config does exactly that will run an ant script before launching tha app in run or debug.  I do use this for ensuring runtime resources are deployed.   This is also specific to an executable config.

What I want is the abilty to run something specified in a MODULE at a point like "before compile" "after compile" "on build" "on rebuild"  (note would get called when compiling building or rebuilding a "module")  and it's configuration stored in the .iml file for the module.